# how to get the list of all my labels text in winform C#

Tags: c#, winforms

i have C# WinForm program.

how to get the list of all my labels text ?

i need to translate to another language.

more explanation:

i have many forms with many labels and textbox.

I do not want to go one by one and change.

That's why I want to get a list of everything

thanks

Comment: Open the form and look at it? Not sure I am understanding your question.

Comment: Do you need to translate the UI into another language?

Comment: Look into the [Controls Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls(v=vs.110).aspx). Loop through it while making sure it's a label, or whatever your control is, and work from there.

Comment: From someone with your reputation I'd expect at least some code of what you tried.

Comment: Controls. OfType<Label>();....

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Comment: "how to get the list of all my labels text in winform C#" – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* narrow your problem down to a concise, focused, simple, short, reproducible [mcve] and ask a specific, focused, narrow question on [so].

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```
foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
        {
            if (control is Label)
            {
                textBox1.AppendText(control.Text);
                //your code here to change the language
            }
        }
```